# Clickonce Deployment server asks for credentials every time I Publish from Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, security, clickonce, authorization, publish

I would like to set it up so that my domain account is allowed to publish a clickonce app without having to provide domain/admin (or local/admin) credentials.  I had this set up once before but do not recall how or where I did this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  I needed to include myself in the OWS group that was created for this Clickonce Web Site ('OWS_##########_admin' account is created when you first extend FrontPage Server Extensions to your website).